# Why are Lagrangian subspaces called 'Lagrangian'?

Tags: differential-geometry, terminology, hamiltonian-formalism, poisson-brackets

I am wondering what the special role of [Lagrangian subspaces](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lagrangian+subspace) (or submanifolds) are in mechanics. Do these subspaces have some sort of special property for which we have some sort of `Lagrangian property?'

The definition I know is, a subspace $Y$ ( submanifold $Y\ $) of a symplectic vector space $(V,\omega)$ (symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$) is called Lagrangian if $\omega|_{Y\times Y}\equiv 0$ and $\dim Y=\frac{1}{2}\dim V$.

Comment: Possibly because the typical example of a Lagrangian subspace is locally spanned by vector fields $\frac{\partial}{\partial q^1}$, $\ldots$, $\frac{\partial}{\partial q^n}$. If we refer to $q^1$, $\ldots$, $q^n$,  $p_1$, $\ldots$, $p_n$, as Hamiltonian coordinates, it is natural to refer to $q^1$, $\ldots$, $q^n$, as Lagrangian coordinates.